# SQL one select statement from one table store data in local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a way to store data from one table in 2 local variables, in one select statement

```
DECLARE @TITLE NVARCHAR()
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR()
```

> So the structure is something like this
>
> experienceID (int) | title (string) | description (string) | userId
>
> ```
>   2                  asd                          1
>   4                  dqd           asdsad         1
>   5                  09                           2
>   7                  456                          2
> ```

What i want to do is check if the user has any experience and if so store it, also in same select i would like to check if the user has ANY description associated with ANY experience and also store it in a variable as well.

So the result will be:

@TITLE = any value from title column if userId = X has experience

@DESCRIPTION = will be first 1st value that is not empty string

EX: for userId = 1 there are experiences so there will be a data for both title and description

EX: for userId = 2 there are experiences but only title has data

EX: for userId = 3 there are no experiences so i don't have any data

For all the cases I need to store the results in the 2 local variables. I don't care if they have or not value.

Comment: Please show your full table structure, some sample data, and ideally the output you want, unless you think your description will be enough.

Comment: And do you want these in normal variables or table variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT @TITLE = MIN(NULLIF(TITLE,'')), @DESCRIPTION = MIN(NULLIF(DESCRIPTION,''))
FROM dbo.Experiences
WHERE UserId = @UserId 
GROUP BY UserId
```

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: Why? I expect that this table stores user-experiences, so probably contains multiple records for each user. OP wants to merge two records which share the same user-id, but where the first contains the (non-null) title and the other the (non-null) description.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @VAR
DECLARE @VAR2

    SET @VAR = SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM SOMETHING WHERE DESCRIPTION NOT NULL AND DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '' AND userid = x
    SET @VAR2 = SELECT ExperienceId FROM SOMETHING where userid = x
```

If you have user table that links to experience table inner join them on experienceid

Tweak the query to your needs.

Comment: you'll want single quotes ('') at the end, not the double ones ("")

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TITLE NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(20)

SELECT @TITLE = title, @DESCRIPTION = description
from mytable
where description is not null

SELECT @TITLE, @DESCRIPTION
```